# ION_AUTH not send email with SMTP

Tags: smtp, ion-auth

I am trigger in controller:

```
if($this->ion_auth->register($login, $pass, $mail, $data, array('2'))){
                        echo $this->ion_auth->messages();
                        echo $this->ion_auth->errors();
                    }else{
                        echo $this->ion_auth->errors();
                    }
```

I am edit config ion_auth:

```
 | Email options.
 | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | email_config:
 |    'file' = Use the default CI config or use from a config file
 |    array  = Manually set your email config settings
 */
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE; // Send Email using the builtin CI email class, if false it will return the code and the identity
$config['email_config'] = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.mail.ru',
    'smtp_user' => 'user',
    'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
);
```

ION_AUTH send me error - activation unseccesefull
Please Help me!
In the database the user entered, but the message is not sent through SMTP.
How can I display debug information from a class in Email newsletters ION_AUTH?